# .htaccess blocking access to PHP page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a directory in my Apache web service.
If I have no configuration file in it I can access a `test.php` file in it,
but as soon as I add the following `.htaccess` file I get a 404 error.

Why and what do needs to be added or changed in the `.htaccess` file?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # NOTE: If you added a web_prefix to config, add it here too, e.g.:
    RewriteRule (.*) /shindig/index.php [L]
    #RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
    # for OAuth signatures to work for POSTed data,
    # always_populate_raw_data needs to be turned on
    php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data On
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: *Access denied*, do you mean forbidden? That isn't a 404...

Comment: I receive 404 and today the error message is in ... Japanese!! The server is in the cloud so I don't really know why Japanese, so I guess is Access forbiden then , but the code is 404 for sure.

Comment: Can you try with removing these two lines php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data On
        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't actualy htaccess file but the index.php that was doing further redirecting to other not existing files.
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily change to [L] to [L,R], and see if it is redirecting.

It may just need removing the / before shindig to get it working.